# How to add connected services on a class library?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

By default, a Class Library project is not set up to add a connected service.

[image]

Is it possible to move our connected services from a Blazor application to a class library? How?

Comment: Which connected services did you use? You can right-click Dependencies and then choose Manage Connected Services.

Comment: Did you try adding another project to this solution? You can add a Class lib project and try.